# Run a method from another method

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Hi I am new to programming, but I can't seem to get this to work.
When I try to run the method from another method every thing stops

```
-(void)rotateMmovment {


}

-(void)stickMove {
[self rotateMmovment];
stick.center = CGPointMake(stick.center.x + x, stick.center.y);
}
```

Comment: Add code through which you call the method. so everyone comes to know what is wrong at here.

Comment: on your question you use  [self performSelector:@selector(methodName)];

Answer (score 1):

First you should check either your method is running or not via using NSLog.its does't seems that you are facing problem due to calling method which have empty body

```
-(void)rotateMmovment {

NSLog(@"My method is running");
}

-(void)stickMove {
[self rotateMmovment];
stick.center = CGPointMake(stick.center.x + x, stick.center.y);
}
```